# Upcasting; why do i get the output 11

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, upcasting

So i ran this code and I don't understand why I got the output 11:

```
class Parent{
   protected int counter;
   public Parent(){counter++;}
}

class Child extends Parent{
   public Child(){
     System.out.print(counter);}
  }
}
public class Test{
   public static void main(String [] args){
      Parent p = new Child();
      System.out.print(p.counter);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

This creates an instance of the `Child` class. This must execute the `Child` class's construcutor. But before that it will run the `Parent` class's constructor. This will set the value of `counter` as 1.

Next, when the child class constructor is run, it prints `1`.

The last part is trivial. Calling `System.out.print(p.counter);` prints another `1`. Thus, the result is `11`.

**Summary:** Parent class's constructor will be executed before the child's.

---

Btw, this doesn't have anything to do with **upcasting**. It is inheritance.